# How to configure FreeNAS for a WireGuard VPN?

Tags: firewall, routing, freebsd, truenas, wireguard

I have a FreeNAS 11.3 system and followed [iXsystems' instructions on setting up WireGuard](https://www.ixsystems.com/blog/wireguard-on-freenas-11-3/). With a simple wg0.conf I'm now able to connect successfully. I'd like to be able to use this setup as a proper VPN, meaning that I can use the tunnel to browse the local network as well as the internet.

On Linux the solution is to use `iptables` to set up a NAT:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

What is the FreeNAS/FreeBSD equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to WireGuard also enable the FreeBSD packet filter pf using rc.conf tunables:

- `wireguard_enable="YES"`
- `wireguard_interfaces="wg0"`
- `pf_enable="YES"`
- `pf_rules="/usr/local/etc/pf.conf"`
- `pflog_enable="YES"`
- `gateway_enable="YES"`
- `ipv6_gateway_enable="YES"`

[image: Final set of Tunables]

- iXsystems recommends `wg0.conf` to live in `/root` and a Post Init Script to copy it to a system location then start WireGuard:

  ```
  mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/wireguard && cp /root/wg0.conf /usr/local/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf && /usr/local/etc/rc.d/wireguard start
  ```

By default pf is configured via `/etc/pf.conf`, but we need to follow the above pattern and copy `/root/pf.conf` to `/usr/local/etc/pf.conf` on startup and have pf use that.

- Add another Post Init Script to feed pf our configuration:

  ```
  cp /root/pf.conf /usr/local/etc/pf.conf && service pf start
  ```

[image: Final scripts]

My `pf.conf` follows. WireGuard IP addresses are arbitrary on an arbitrary subnet. pf will route and NAT from this subnet to the rest of the network. I don't know of a way to do this without these arbitrary, but static, IP addresses.

```
# Interfaces
ext_if = "igb0"
wireguard_if = "wg0"

# Wireguard Settings
wireguard_net_v4 = "192.168.222.0/24"
wireguard_net_v6 = "fc::0/64"

# Rules must be in order: options, normalization, queueing, translation, filtering

# Options
set skip on lo

# Translation
# Nat all wireguard to non-wireguard traffic
nat on $ext_if inet  from $wireguard_net_v4 to { any, !$wireguard_net_v4 } -> ($ext_if)
#nat on $ext_if inet6 from $wireguard_net_v6 to { any, !$wireguard_net_v6 } -> {$ext_if}

# Filtering
pass inet all
pass inet6 all
```

(uncomment the ipv6 NAT if your ipv6 works)

My FreeNAS server's `wg0.conf`:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = foofafi
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 192.168.222.1/32, fc::1/64

[Peer]
PublicKey = CLIENT1_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 192.168.222.2/32, fc::2/128
```

Laptop client configuration:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = blahblahblah
Address = 192.168.222.2/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = dynamicdns.example.com:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Thanks to https://gist.github.com/apearson/168b244b4735cceff9809ef3d07f4df5 for a nearly working config!

See also [pf docs](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-pf.html) and [this](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/wireguard-setup-with-pf-problems.72623/).

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful.